# about javascript - asynchronous calls, difference in these two programs executions?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I was learning about asynchronous calls in javascript. That's two confusing by the way!

today I wrote these two programs and results are different. can somebody explain in depth difference.

```
setTimeout(function(){console.log(5)},5);
console.log(55);
setTimeout(function(){console.log(4)},4);
console.log(44);
setTimeout(function(){console.log(2)},2);
console.log(22);
setTimeout(function(){console.log(3)},3);
console.log(33);
```

and this -

```
setTimeout(function(){console.log(5)},5000);
console.log(55);
setTimeout(function(){console.log(4)},4000);
console.log(44);
setTimeout(function(){console.log(2)},2000);
console.log(22);
setTimeout(function(){console.log(3)},3000);
console.log(33);
```

**only difference is their timeout duration. I also tried with** *hundreds* **and** *tens* **, you can also try.**

I guess, their output may depend on CPU speed and many other things.

I got this from first one.. executed [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs_terminal_online.php)

```
55
44
22
33
5
2
3
4
```

and from second one.. (as expected)

```
55
44
22
33
2
3
4
5
```

THANKS!

EDIT: later, for first code piece, I also tried in Ubuntu - nodejs - v5.12.0

I got 5 4 2 3 (new permutation)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified

Comment: Yeah, 5 2 3 4 is really weird. 4 2 3 5 I would have expected because the minimum timeout is 4ms, so the latter three would have the same timeout and be executed in the order they were registered, but apparently there's more than that.

Comment: @Bergi did u also get same output?

Comment: @SushilKumarJain I didn't try it out before, but when I do now (in Opera 12) I actually do get 4 2 3 5 :-) What environment are you using?

Comment: I am using [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs_terminal_online.php).

Comment: Now I also tried in Ubuntu - nodejs - v5.12.0

I got 5 4 2 3 (new permutation)

Answer (score -1):

This is not easy to understand at the beginning because **you think that every statement of code it has to be executed when the above has finished**, but **in JavaScript it isn't like this**. Look your second example, why the last `console.log` function inside that `setTimeout` is printed the first? It's something wrong? No, it's JavaScript's nature.

To understand it, think that every function that it's not executed instantaneously **it's executed in background**. Imagine that there is a traffic jam in one rail highway, why not use the others? It would be stupid don't use the others to reduce traffic and, even others vehicles go lower than others, they are contributing to reduce traffic. Although, despite Javascript is asynchronous, you can set a synchronous nature but, personally, I do not recommend it.

Comment: OP does understand how asynchrony works and knows they are not executed in the order they appear in the code, see his expectations about second example. He is confused about the order of execution in the first example.

Comment: I think that I've explained why the result does not means that its code is wrong or its CPU is not the responsible of the output, but the Javascript nature.

Comment: @PinaGamer, I know little about asynchronous calls and non-blocking concepts. I want to understand them more, though. Now I want to know, about first CODE.